# SQL - round down to two decimal places

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to round down to two decimal places in SQL. Example as below:

```
2.96 --> 2.50
5.90 --> 5.50
1.80 --> 1.50
```

Is it possible to round to this way? I tried to do round like

```
select round(2.96, 0)
```

but it will turn into

```
3.00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
select floor(col * 2) / 2.0
```

If you only want to see two decimal places, convert to a numeric:

```
select convert(numeric(10, 2), floor(col * 2) / 2.0)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5a822ecd0d7c8a81f9d909d92ffc7ee2) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: it works! Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @bennybenito From [`Floor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified numeric expression." That means the first expression will round negative values "down", e.g. `-2.96` to `-3.0`. `floor( abs( -2.96 * 2.0 ) ) / 2.0 * sign( -2.96 )` returns `-2.5`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach.

Imagine that the value is 1.20.

```
SELECT (1.20+(CEILING(1.20)-1.20))-(0.50)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much!